# What is the difference between IoT and M2M?

Tags: embedded, protocols, iot, paho

There is a sentence in Eclipse Paho Project website such as;
"The Paho project provides scalable open-source client implementations of open and standard messaging protocols aimed at new, existing, and emerging applications for **Machine‑to‑Machine (M2M)** and **Internet of Things (IoT)**."

I am confused a little bit. What is the difference between IoT and M2M?

Answer (score 2):

**M2M** is basically communication between a machine or a device with a remote computer.

There are three processes involved in the M2M as mentioned below
•    It connects the device to the cloud. 
•    Manage the device. 
•    Collects the machine and/or sensor data.

**IoT** goes beyond the M2M periphery and it basically represents things connecting with the systems,people and other things.

M2M can be thought of as integral to the IoT. IoT is bigger than M2M

Comment: check this to know more about M2M : http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Articles/M2M.html

Comment: check this for IoT : http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Articles/IoT-Internet-of-Things.html

Answer (score 2):

IoT is much more than M2M. In M2M the user is not involved (think about billing system for energy meters at home, you just receive the invoice).
In IoT the user is into the circle and has an active role. This is related to the fact that now user has a smartphone on hands.
IoT in the future will be even more. Things will talk to other things in order to avoid user to have an active role, but the user decide or suggest those things how to act/react.

It's just the beginning, it's gonna be fun!

Answer (score 1):

Devices, computers, and machines were already connected by the time Kevin Ashton coined the term Internet of Things. The concept gained popularity for its ability to connect the unconnected – physical-first objects. The meaning and application of the term IoT will continue to evolve as new connected technologies emerge, replacing physical-first objects with smart connected devices. Examples of IoT include connected cars, smart meters, and smart cities, wearables etc.

M2M means machine to machine communication, is basically communication between a machine or a device with a remote computer. It is a data communication standard. M2M is also named as Machine Type Communication (MTC) in 3GPP.
There are three processes involved in an M2M communication:

- It connects the device to the cloud.
- Manage the device.
- Collects the machine and/or sensor data.

M2M the subset of IoT, initially represented closed, point-to-point communication between physical-first objects. Some experts define M2M as a subset of IoT, while others like to call IoT as an evolved version of machine to machine. Either way, M2M is more recently referred to technologies that enable communication between machines without human intervention. Examples include telemetry, traffic control, robotics, and other applications involving device-to-device communications.

The concepts of IoT and M2M are inherently subjected to the confusion associated with meaning, use cases, and adoption. Traditional M2M solutions typically rely on point-to-point communications using embedded hardware modules and either cellular or wired networks. In contrast, IoT solutions rely on IP-based networks to interface device data to a cloud or middleware platform. Though M2M solutions offer remote access to machine data, these data are traditionally targeted at point solutions in service management applications. Rarely, if ever, are the data integrated with enterprise applications to help improve overall business performance.

There is also a clear difference in the applications of these technologies. M2M solutions, because of their limited scope, are confined to creating a network of machines that work in synchronization. On the other hand, IoT creates 360° solutions that allow for flexible responses and multi-level communication.

Integration of device and sensor data with big data, analytics and other enterprise applications is a core concept behind the emerging IoT. The cloud-based architecture also makes IoT inherently more scalable thereby eliminating the need for incremental hard-wired connections and SIM card installations. This is one reason why M2M is often referred to as “plumbing,” while IoT is a universal enabler.
Here's http://www.iot.qa/2017/11/what-is-difference-between-iot-and-m2m.html!

Answer (score 0):

The Internet of Things (IoT) refers to billions of interconnected physical devices around the world that are collecting and sharing data. A physical object can be transformed into an IoT device if it can be connected to the internet & sensors and controlled in that way. The sensors are collecting extremely sensitive data in many cases, and send it to cloud via gateways.

Machine-to-machine communication, or M2M, is exactly as it sounds: two machines “communicating,” or exchanging data, without human interfacing or interaction. This includes serial connection, powerline connection (PLC), or wireless communications in the industrial Internet of Things (IoT). Switching over to wireless has made M2M communication much easier and enabled more applications to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet of Things (IoT) refers to a system of interrelated, internet-connected objects that communicate over wireless networks